# Protecting my code from zombies from completion blocks

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I'm familiar with the delegate pattern and nilling my delegates, especially when doing asynchronous calls which are still in progress when my view controllers disappear. I nil the delegate, and the callback successfully returns on a nil object.

I'm now experimenting with using completion blocks to make my code a little easier to read.

I call a network service from my view controller, and pass a block which updates my UITableView. Under normal circumstances it works fine. However, if I leave the view before it completes, the completion handler block is executed - but the UITableView is now a zombie.

Whats the usual pattern for handling this?

**UPDATE WITH CODE SAMPLE**

This is an iPad app, I have two view controllers on screen at once, like a split view. One is the detail, and the other is a grid of images. I click an image and it tell the detail to load the info. However, if i click the images too fast before they have chance to do the network call - I have the problems. On changing images the code below is called which counts the favourites of a image....

So here is my dilemma, if I use the code below - it works fine but it leaks in instruments if you switch images before the network responds.

If I remove the __block and pass in self, then it crashes with zombies.

I can't win... I'm sure i'm missing something fundamental about using blocks.

```
__block UITableView *theTable = [self.table retain];
__block IndexedDictionary *tableData = [self.descriptionKeyValues retain];
FavouritesController *favourites = [Container controllerWithClass:FavouritesController.class];
[favourites countFavouritesForPhoto:self.photo 
                         completion:^(int favesCount) {

                             [tableData insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", favesCount]   
                                              forKey:@"Favourites:" atIndex:1];                 
                             [theTable reloadData];

                             [tableData release];
                             [theTable release];
                         }];
```

Any tips? Thanks

**SECOND UPDATE**

I changed the way I loaded the favourites. Instead of the favourites being a singleton, I create an instance on each photo change. By replacing this and killing the old one - the block has nowhere to callback (i guess it doesn't even exist) and my code now just looks like the below, and it appear to be working:

```
[self.favourites countFavouritesForPhoto:self.photo 
                         completion:^(int favesCount) {      
                             [self.descriptionKeyValues insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", favesCount]   
                                              forKey:@"Favourites:" atIndex:1];                 
                             [self.table reloadData];
                         }];
```

It doesn't leak, and doesn't appear to be crashing either.

Comment: `retain` + `release`? But I'm not sure that it is guarantied that completion block will be executed

Comment: In this instance, I think you're right. I went back to blocks programming guide and re-read that "Object variables marked with the __block storage type modifier, however, are not retained" .... which I was doing. However, this is because my view controller was still there... what if it wasn't? Or is it always there because of the block keeping it alive? Ahh brain ache...

Comment: +1 for 'Protecting my code from zombies' ;-)

Comment: What about getting reference to that object via any method? In that method check if view controller still exist.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you test that the tableview is not nil at the start of the block. It sounds like the tableview is properly discarded when its parent view goes off-screen, so after that point, no tableview operations are valid.

Retaining the UITableView within the block is a bad idea, because datasource/tableview updates can result in implicit method calls and notifications that will not be relevant if the tableview is not on-screen.

Comment: If I'd pushed a view controller onto the navigation stack, my tableview wouldn't be nil. I'm going to throw together another sample project to test this a bit more. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Block will retain any object that it references, except for those annotated with `__block`. If you want not to execute completion blocks at all, just make some property like `isCancelled` and check whether it is `YES` before calling completion block.

Comment: Yup I read that about the retaining of __block vars. isCancelled seems like an interesting pattern, but whenever I see BOOL's thrown in it always smells bad to me.

Comment: It is used by Cocoa's NSOperation so i think it's not bad. Your task can have different states. Delayed, cancelled, in progress, etc. It's up to you to maintain it or not.

Comment: I'll have a look, maybe it really is the way i have to go. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So you have a background operation which has to call back another object after it finishes and the object can be destroyed in the meantime. The crashes you describe happen when you have non retained references. The problem as you see is that the referred object goes away and the pointer is invalid. Usually, what you do is unregister the delegate inside the dealloc method so that the background task continues, and whenever it is ready to communicate the results back it says "*Shoot, my callback object is nil*", and at least it doesn't crash.

Still, handling manually weak references is tedious and error prone. You can forget to nil a delegate inside a dealloc method and it may go without notice for months before you encounter a situation where the code crashes.

If you are targeting iOS 5.0 I would read up upon [ARC](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html) and the weak references it provides. If you don't want to use ARC, or need to target pre 5.x devices, I would recommend using zeroing weak reference libraries like [MAZeroingWeakRef](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-07-16-zeroing-weak-references-in-objective-c.html) which work also for 3.x devices.

With either ARC's weak references or MAZeroingWeakRef, you would implement the background task with one of these fancy weak reference objects pointing back to your table. Now if the pointed object goes away, the weak pointer will nil itself and your background task won't crash.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but you've gone slightly off topic. I'm not new to this. I know how to use delegates and I'm not using ARC. My question is regarding patterns with asynchronous block completion handlers. However, regarding your answer - I would nil my delegates in viewWillDisappear, not the dealloc method which may be too late - and you only have to use your app on a slow connection, or use the network optimiser to slow down your simulator network and you can expose latent delegate callbacks in seconds, instead of months.

Comment: You asked "What's the usual pattern for handling this", I answered: either nil the callback or use zeroing weak references. What is offtopic? That's my current programming pattern for dealing with asynchronous block completion handlers. Also, if you nil in viewWillDisappear that's too early, since you won't receive the callback if the task finishes while you present a modal view controller in the meantime.

Comment: Maybe off topic was the wrong phrase... but you quoted the delegate pattern, which I said I know and use. From my experience, nilling the delegate in dealloc was too late. I guess it depends on the use case though,with modals viewWillDisappear does sound too early. Thanks for the weak pointer info.